# How to ask somebody what position they are working as?

Tags: usage, conversation

Sometimes when talking to a person newly met in a office, we need to ask them which position they are working in. How to ask that ?

I have the following lines in my head, but not sure if they will sound normal, or are even correct.

- Hi. What post have you got ?
- Hi. What is your job here ?
- Hi. Which position are you in?

Please help me.

Comment: 'post' sounds a bit US Eng to me, role might work... "What's your role here?" which is non-specific enough to allow them to either give you their job title, or expand to an actual description of what they do. [not that there's anything wrong with it sounding US, just I think role might be more international]

Comment: what's the relation, MM, MF, FM or FF? because we care.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry take it as MX.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to start by asking where they work within the company; that is, ask a question that goes something along these lines:

> Which branch do you work for?
>   What section do you work in?
>   Which department head do you work for?

One or two of those quesitons might give you the answer that you seek; the person might say:

> *I work in finance as a programmer in the payroll department*.

If not, though – if the person just says something like, "I work in finance" – you can always ask a 
follow-on question:

> And what's your role there?
>   And what do you do in that department?

Answer (score 0):

For starters, after 'Hi', introduce yourself - 'I'm Mikey'. If you have a higher position than they do, the last thing you want to do is scare them.

Next, if, as your Q implies, you are higher ranked, surely you should know their position, but allowing for that you don't:

All three are fine. Tailor each one to the person you are asking. I would go with 2:

> Hello. I'm Mikey. You are?, ... and what is your job here?

because it asks the person what they DO, not what the name of the job is.